# Allow horizontal scrolling only in the core-plot barchart?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, core-plot, bar-chart

I am using core-plot lib to draw bar charts in my app like this [image: ......]

My problem is that i want the enabling of grapgh movement only in horizontal direction so that I can see the records for a long period of time, But the problem is that i just wnt to keep the y axis fixed to its place,

How can i do this?

Waiting for help....

Comment: I don't know why you rolled back my edit last time. Imgur is a lot faster than FreeImageHosting.net, which times out whenever I try to load the image as part of this page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only recently has rudimentary user interaction been enabled in Core Plot graphs.  To enable scrolling in any direction, you can set the `allowsUserInteraction` property of the plot space to YES.

We currently have no means of locking that movement to one direction.  The scrolling action takes place in the `-pointingDeviceDraggedAtPoint:` method on CPXYPlotSpace, so you could subclass CPXYPlotSpace, copy over its implementation of that method, and alter it to only allow movement in the X direction.  Even better, we'd appreciate any contributions to extend the functionality of the CPXYPlotSpace to add support for unidirectional movement.

Comment: Hi Brad, I implemented the solution as you said at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899553/keeping-the-y-axis-fixed-at-place But still I am not able to fix the origin

Comment: @BradLarson is there built in support added for this yet, or not?

Answer (score 22):

If you are using Core-Plot 0.2.2 or greater (possibly earlier) then you can add a method on your plot space's delegate to handle the following:

```
-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)displacement {
    return CGPointMake(displacement.x, 0);
}
```

This will restrict the plot movement to horizontal only. This assumes you have allowed interacting with the plot space by setting allowsUserInteraction = YES.

Comment: I was only able to get this to work after doing a hg clone of the repository.  I did not have any luck using the installers.

Comment: Works fine on CorePlot v1.1

Answer (score 16):

Limit scrolling by setting a delegate (i.e., CPPlotSpaceDelegate) on the plot space and implement the willChangePlotRangeTo method. You can do other cool things at the same time. Here's how I limit the display to quadrant one:

```
- (CPPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space
    willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPPlotRange *)newRange
            forCoordinate:(CPCoordinate)coordinate {

    // Display only Quadrant I: never let the location go negative.
    //
    if (newRange.locationDouble < 0.0F) {
        newRange.location = CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0);
    }

    // Adjust axis to keep them in view at the left and bottom;
    // adjust scale-labels to match the scroll.
    //
    CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)self.graph.axisSet;
        if (coordinate == CPCoordinateX) {
            axisSet.yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = newRange.location;
            axisSet.xAxis.titleLocation = CPDecimalFromFloat(newRange. newRange.locationDouble +
                                                             (newRange.lengthDouble / 2.0F));
        } else {
            axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = newRange.location;
            axisSet.yAxis.titleLocation = CPDecimalFromFloat(newRange.locationDouble +
                                                             (newRange.lengthDouble / 2.0F));
        }

    return newRange;
}
```

See: CPPlotSpace.h

Comment: newRange.doublePrecisionLocation is now newRange.locationDouble

Comment: newRange.doublePrecisionLength is now newRange.lengthDouble

Comment: I'm getting assignment to read only property on: newRange.location = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0);

Comment: I've added the updated code that works with CorePlot 1.5.1 here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24525631/607

Answer (score 13):

I used a simple way to "disable" the vertical scroll

```
    CPPlotRange *globalYRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromDouble(minY) length:CPDecimalFromDouble(maxY)];
    plotSpace.globalYRange = globalYRange;
```

For, minY and maxY I put the values I displayed, like that the vertical limits are what you see, so you can't vertical scroll

It worked for me, after I saw your topic, so I wanted to complete your answers with mine

Comment: Is it possible to limit the scrolling to the negative x-axis?

Answer (score 11):

Using CorePlot 1.0 -- To restrict scrolling to just horizontal and scaling as well, I implemented the two CPTPlotSpaceDelegate methods: method by Steve Tranby with a modified method suggested by supperAly/edo42.

```
-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)displacement
{
    return CGPointMake(displacement.x, 0);
}

-(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
    if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateY) {
    newRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace*)space).yRange;
    }
    return newRange;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind also share the code of how to setup graph? i mean the start point of setup the CPTPlotSpace at the beginning. I followed your solution, but my one is still not working. Please help! >.<

Comment: You are the man... Thanks for the wonderful answer Jay... :) Voted up

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do to fix the y axis after Answer 4 with the comment incl. ( `newRange.doublePrecisionLocation` is now `newRange.locationDouble` ) is to set `plotSpace.globalYRange = plotSpace.yRange;`

Answer (score 3):

i am using CorePlot 0.2.2

```
-(CPPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPCoordinate)coordinate;
{
    CPXYPlotSpace * plot_space = (CPXYPlotSpace*)space;
    plot_space.globalYRange = plot_space.yRange;
    return newRange;
}
```

u will need to add CPPlotSpaceDelegate,CPLineStyleDelegate protocols to your controller

and add (for CPLineStyleDelegate)

```
-(void)lineStyleDidChange:(CPLineStyle *)lineStyle
{
//empty
}
```

the system will keep the original range of y axis

Answer (score 2):

thanks to supperAly 
when my interface implements "CPPlotSpaceDelegate" protocol
and the project can not be complied normally , and shows that:
 `your interface xxx doesn't implement 'CPLineStyleDelegate' protocol`, which make me confuse. 
so i add the method : `-(void)lineStyleDidChange:(CPLineStyle *)lineStyle { //empty }` 
for CPLineStyleDelegate and add `<CPLineStyleDelegate>` to my interface and the problems have gone.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is based on [Tom Donaldson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2580609/607) and has been tested with CorePlot 1.5.1:

```
- (CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space
      willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange
              forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
    CPTMutablePlotRange *range = [CPTMutablePlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:newRange.location length:newRange.length];

    // Display only Quadrant I: never let the location go negative.
    //
    if (range.locationDouble < 0.0F)
    {
        range.location = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0);
    }

    // Adjust axis to keep them in view at the left and bottom;
    // adjust scale-labels to match the scroll.
    //
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) space.graph.axisSet;
    if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateX)
    {
        axisSet.yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = range.location;
        axisSet.xAxis.titleLocation               = CPTDecimalFromDouble(range.locationDouble + (range.lengthDouble / 2.0F));
    }
    else
    {
        axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = range.location;
        axisSet.yAxis.titleLocation               = CPTDecimalFromDouble(range.locationDouble + (range.lengthDouble / 2.0F));
    }

    return range;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the

```
-(void)scaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)plotAreaPoint`
```

function in CPTXYPlotSpace and take out all the code related to the movement for y axis.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew S: "I'm getting 'assignment to read-only property' on 
newRange.location = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0);"

I had that, too, and, following the "CurvedScatterPlot" example in the Core-Plot gallery app, used a mutable copy of newRange in plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate: ...

CPTMutablePlotRange *changedRange = [newRange mutableCopy];

changedRange.location = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(0.0F); then passes muster and I used changedRange in the if...else block.