# How to draw a line chart that supports drag around?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-graphics, draw

I want to draw a line chart, displaying data from a database read. I use the X-axis to record time, I want the chart to support pan and zoom.

I  use core plot, I created one demo, but it gives 4 errors. The other demo work the same wrong. I use Xcode 4.3.3 and iOS 5.1 SDK.

[image: Screenshot of the errors]

Comment: If possible, please add a link to the demo project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow only horizontal scrolling (and/or zooming) in Core Plot, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9721739/1044642) by Jay from another question. Here's the code from his answer:

Use this to allow only horizontal scrolling/panning:

```
-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)displacement
{
    return CGPointMake(displacement.x, 0);
}
```

Use this to allow only horizontal zooming:

```
-(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
    if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateY) {
    newRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace*)space).yRange;
    }
    return newRange;
}
```

About the errors you're getting: they don't really seem to be directly related to Core Plot. They appear because you haven't declared the ivars in your header file. (*Use of undeclared identifier _titleFont*, etc)

Comment: I want to know exactly which header file is missing?I run the CORE PLOT own code case。Thanks man  or how can I find the missing header?

Comment: The photo is upload on the main question. doxygen config flie not exist

Comment: @NeilBee: I don't know why you get that error, but you are trying to build the documentation and not the application itself. Change the build target to your application target in the upper left corner of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/), probably the best framework for plots and charts so far.

Here is a tutorial on *raywenderlich* that introduces you to using it:

[Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1) and [Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2).

Comment: I wonder if there a line chart demo support touch the chart view and can  drag around by X axis.

Comment: Do you mean you want to scroll horizontally only ?

Comment: Yes,and as I download the 0.9Core Plot . I work one example it  exists 4 errors.I ures X-code 4.3.3 . Image I upload to the mian question.

Answer (score 0):

CorePlot does support pan, but is rather slow. There are several commercial tools for iOS charting:

- [ShinobiControls](http://www.shinobicontrols.com)
- [www.threedgraphics.com](http://www.threedgraphics.com)
- [iPhone Charting Library for iPhone Objective-C](http://www.keepedge.com/products/iphone_charting/)

ShinobiControls supports pan and pinch gestures.

NOTE: I am associated with the ShinobiControls team.

Comment: Hey ColinE, I want to plot a line of data and then allow the user to draw a trend line. Does ShinobiControls support allowing a user to draw on the screen (ios)?