# Core Plot Scroll Horizontally Scroll Show show positive quadrants

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using core plot in an iOS app and have it displaying a bar chart that scrolls horizontally only. This is to allow larger data sets than the vertically oriented screen will fit in (I'm not intending on using a landscape orientation).

I've got that bit working well. However, I want to

1) prevent the user from scrolling past the zero value into the unused negative quadrant of the table.

2) Stop the horizontal scrolling when the user gets to the last bar in the chart.

I did query the third poster in this thread: [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892544/allow-horizontal-scrolling-only-in-the-core-plot-barchart) but did not get a response. He has suggested an approach that cannot possibly work (or not at least with the version I have). He is assigning to read only variables of the CPTPlotRange range class (he refers to this as CPPlotRange as I guess he's using an earlier version) with this line of code.

```
newRange.location = CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `globalXRange` of the plot space to a range with `location` = zero and `range` = the location of the last bar (plus an offset for the width of the bar).

Comment: What do you mean by globalXRange, plotSpace has not such variable.

Comment: Ah I see now. What a convoluted mess. So to restrict the movement one must tinker with the axis range?!?  Seems like a recipe for mistakes. Surely there must be a better way to implement this.

Comment: Not the `xRange`, the `globalXRange`. Set it once and the plot space will allow the `xRange` to scroll only within that range. You can also do this with a plot space delegate, but for the case where you know the scrolling limits, using the global range is much easier.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a little late, but for anyone looking for a simple quick answer (like I came looking for)

Just put this in

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

CPTPlotRange *globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(HOW HIGH YOU WANT YOUR GRAPH)];
plotSpace.globalYRange = globalYRange;
CPTPlotRange *globalxRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble() length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(HOW WIDE YOU WANT YOUR GRAPH)];
plotSpace.globalXRange = globalxRange;
```